# ¿Cómo reasignar el value por defecto de un input text C#?

Tags: c#, html5

Necesito saber como reasignar el value que tiene por defecto un input tipo text.

Por ejemplo si tengo:

```html
<input runat="server" id="TextPer_5" class="Text_Personas" value="Nombre Materia..." type="text" />
```

Como notan el input tipo text tiene un value="Nombre Materia..."
Necesito que al guardar el botón limpie el input pero que reasigne de nuevo este valor y no solo que lo deje vacío.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr tu objetivo, puedes usar el attributo placeholder.

**ejemplo:**

```html
<input placeholder="Nombre Materia...">
```

El ejemplo de arriba seria lo mas simple que podrias usar.

Ahora resolviendo tu duda, seria insertando ese texto con javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('entrada').value = "Nombre Materia...";
```

```html
<input id="entrada">
```

Comment: Gracias lo intentaré.